# Integration tests for Office 365 Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, integration-testing

I have not been able to find guidelines to introduce integration tests for an Office 365 Outlook Add-in using a browser automation tool like Cypress or Selenium, and I'm looking for alternatives.

My team is currently using Cypress for automation tests, and the only way I was able to run tests on an Outlook Add-in was to make the Add-in run outside of the Office 365 Outlook environment in a standalone mode.

For the standalone mode, I had to mock the JavaScript API Office object (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js) as well as mock the Office rest API responses to get a couple of tests running.

It's a very painful process, so I would like to know if there's a better way to implement the integration tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like the process you're using is correct, and there are no better alternatives for integration tests for Outlook add-ins.

We suggest that you add this request for better add-in integration tests to our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to automate e2e-Tests for Office Add-ins (real environment, no mocking of APIs required) using Appium and WinAppDriver. The HTML Elements of your app can be accessed by their id or via other methods. [This gh repo](https://github.com/phlppnhllngr/office-addin-integration-testing) contains a how-to.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Appium seems legit. We're going to explore it and will post back here if we get useful information. Currently, we use GhostInspector to test Outlook add-ins in OWA. Would love to see more tutorials on the subject (using Appium to test Outlook Add-Ins in Outlook Desktop).